# How is <br> actually implemented in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox

For the formal implementation of `<br>`, I would expect one of the following:

1. [HTML5 > Rendering > Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#phrasing-content-0)
   `br { content: '\A'; white-space: pre; }`
2. [Default style sheet for HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html)
   `br:before { content: "\A"; white-space: pre-line }`

But if I do "Inspect Element" on the `<br>` tag, I do not see any user agent styles in Firefox.
However the line-break is still there.

Is it implemented as a special case within the browser?

Comment: Would it really surprise you?

Comment: No, but my goal is getting an answer, not necessarily being surprised by it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `<br>` is implemented as a special-cased box type in Gecko.  See http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/generic/nsBRFrame.cpp for the implementation.